# how to solve .htaccess file subdirectory issue on godaddy server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

That is my .htaccess file code. It is not working for subdirectory on godaddy server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below the code to solved my subdirectory .htaccess issue on godaddy server.

```
# Options
    Options -Multiviews
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    #Enable mod rewrite
    RewriteEngine On
    #the location of the root of your site
    #if writing for subdirectories, you would enter /subdirectory
    RewriteBase /discussion_forum/

    #Removes access to CodeIgniter system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #’system’ can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn’t true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    #This last condition enables access to the images and css
    #folders, and the robots.txt file
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: So what do you get if you add index.php back into your URL?

Comment: if we add index.php into our website url . there no any issue and we will get same output.but why we use the .htaccess file? because we want user friendly url for SEO.